# ClamTk update message

Tags: updates

l have clam av/tk installed on my ubuntu 18.04.1lts, l thought it was suppost to update itself but it it says an update is available when l open the clam tk window.Why wont it update itself how do l fix this,
l did try this:

```
sysadmin@DELL-LAP:~$ sudo freshclam
[sudo] password for sysadmin: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for sysadmin: 
ERROR: /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log is locked by another process
ERROR: Problem with internal logger (UpdateLogFile = /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log).
sysadmin@DELL-LAP:~$ /etc/clamav/freshclam.conf
bash: /etc/clamav/freshclam.conf: Permission denied
sysadmin@DELL-LAP:~$ /etc/clamav/freshclam.conf
bash: /etc/clamav/freshclam.conf: Permission denied
sysadmin@DELL-LAP:~$ xxxxxxxx
xxxxxxx: command not found
sysadmin@DELL-LAP:~$
```

l do see this red cirle message top right of my laptop saying broken count ect, this usally means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies,
is this something dto do with it thanks can anyone please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ClamTk update message is for the GUI. You can check what version you have now, by clicking on the "yellow star" icon. Go to [the home page](https://dave-theunsub.github.io/clamtk/), then download [the update](https://bitbucket.org/davem_/clamtk/downloads/clamtk_5.26-1_all.deb) and install version 5.26, and any appropriate add-on files, then close and re-open ClamTk to confirm that the update message is gone.

For virus signature updates, first click the "Scheduler" icon and confirm that you have updates configured. Then click the "Update" icon to manually update the virus signatures.

<strike>The red circle icon is a different problem. Usually it's broken packages. Start `Synaptic` and go to the Edit menu, and select "Fix broken packages". Repeat this until it doesn't complain any more. Reboot the computer and the red circle icon should be gone. If it isn't, more work needs to be done on your system.</strike>

Comment: why on the virus scanner the message says an update is available is set to update daily at a set time. l have reinstallked clam av/tk as advised the message wont go away

Comment: @user905582 as I mention in my answer, the ClamTk GUI needs updating. Open ClamTk, click on the yellow star icon, and if the "About" info doesn't read as version 5.26, then you need to update the GUI. Then click on the "Home page" link, download the update, install it, close and restart ClamTk, and you should be fine.

Comment: l tried all day yesterday on that site to update given but couldn't work out how to update to 5.26,since giving me update link it just did it so easy, so l now have 5,26 and message gone.It says l have updates configured to automatically receive updates so l presume that's why it wont let me chose a time to update my signatures and l have set the scan at 1 hour.l tried also to update as advised but wont do anything so l guess being set at automatic that's why..

Comment: If this is ok please tell me and thanks for all your help you have been great.As you have guessed l am setting it up for 1st time use as a new user thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

ClamTK by default does not call for an update to signatures automatically. You can click on the Update section to do it manually, or you can set up a schedule to update daily at a set time. You can also set it to scan in the background at a set time. If you're concerned about unmet dependencies for ClamTK, just remove it and reinstall.

Comment: l already have clamav-daemon installed which has the updating shell in it, the red cirlce has gone thanks still working on the clamtk update

Answer (score 0):

To get the latest version, go to the downloads page [here](https://gitlab.com/dave_m/clamtk/-/wikis/Downloads).

Then make sure you have closed Clamscan and download the install package for your version of Linux.